# Bootstrap 3 input type file doesn't go with the div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, input

The "browse" input doesn't go with the center in the div, but the button does.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use 'form-control' class to browse input or else you can use 'offset' class to you input to center the element, please refer the following link

[bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake. I just need to add `margin auto`.

```
<div class="input-group" style="margin: auto">
```